# How to translate enum on Rails_admin?

Tags: enums, internationalization, rails-admin

I have problem on translating enum content (gender).
The aiit_member.rb file in app/models folder is like this:

```
class AiitMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthday, :kana_name, :gender, :memo, :name

  has_one :privacy
  has_many :prospects
  has_many :exam_lists
  has_many :student_lists

  rails_admin do

        list do
            field :name
            field :kana_name
            field :birthday
            field :gender, :enum do
                enum do
                  ['male', 'female']
                end
             end
            field :memo
        end

        edit do
            field :name
            field :kana_name
            field :birthday
            field :gender, :enum do
                enum do
                  ['male', 'female']
                end
             end
            field :memo
        end
  end

end
```

and I add translate content everywhere in translation_ja.yml and ja.yml but none of them work.
I searched for this problem but can't find the answer.

(new)
I don't know which file (ja.yml or translation_ja.yml or rails_admin.ja.yml) to write the translate content ? Like:

```
    enum:
      gender:
        Male: 男
        Female: 女
```

Could somebody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please see https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Enumeration

```
edit do
  field :name
  field :kana_name
  field :birthday
  field :gender, :enum do
      enum do
        Hash[ ['Male', 'Female'].zip(['male', 'female']) ]
      end
   end
  field :memo
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Both way can enable the select box, but I don't know which file (ja.yml or translation_ja.yml or rails_admin.ja.yml) to write the translate content ? Like
  enum:
    gender:
      Male: 男
      Female: 女